# Movie where people are trapped with no connection to the outside world but have food and water

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie I remember is not from Hollywood, below are some of the scene references.

Theme of the story is people get trapped in certain places (with recurring food and water for their survival) and have no connection with the outside world and ultimately they die (because of ageing). Of all the people who get trapped, one particular person, who is about to die, recalls that he should have not entered into (that place where they are about to get trapped) and informs the same to the youngest of them. But the situations will be in such a way that it lures the people to get into it.

Some of the scenes I have in my mind are:

- A family (mom, dad, daughter and a son) goes on a family vacation in a car. In their journey, they hear a blast very far away. This is when they get trapped. They finally realise they are trapped. They lose the asthma inhaler of the daughter, as the bottle shatters falling on the road. All they have is a gas station, where they have all the supplies they need until they die of ageing.
- When the dad is about to die, he recalls and explains to his son that it is a curse like thing and you will be lured in to get trapped. And the father dies. Like the father said, there comes a police car. And the person who survived gets into the police car and here starts the loop again.

Comment: sounds a bit like Dead End to me but some plot points are missing so it's not that probably

Comment: Also somewhat similar to [_Splinter_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splinter_(2008_film)) but it doesn't match the ageing or loop aspects.

Comment: What do you mean by "not from Hollywood"? Also, was it in color or black and white? Do you remember seeing it on a particular TV station or was it in the theater?

Comment: Sounds like an episode of The Twilight Zone but I will need more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*El Incidente*, a 2014 Mexican movie.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incident_(2014_film)):

> After tragedy strikes them, two different groups of people find themselves stuck in their current location, unable to escape from an infinitely repeating road and an endless staircase, respectively. [...]
>
> Elsewhere, Sandra and her two children, Daniel and Camila, prepare to visit her ex-husband. [...] **On the way, they stop at a gas station**, where Roberto carelessly offers fruit juice to Camila. Camila has an allergic reaction to it, **which brings on an asthma attack. After Roberto accidentally destroys her inhaler**, an accident he insists was fated to happen, **a loud explosion sounds in the distance**. Sandra asks Daniel to retrieve the backup inhaler, but he reveals that he forgot to pack it. [...]
>
> As he dies, Roberto urges Daniel to break the cycle of creating new dimensions by refusing to follow his fate. Marco/Daniel urges Oliver to break the cycle as well by refusing to follow his fate. Daniel and Oliver find they are now free to leave their dimension. Each initially hesitates but follows his fate. **Daniel enters a police car** and becomes Marco, off to arrest Oliver and Carlos.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie loop trapped site:imdb.com/title`. It was the first result, but I had to check the Wikipedia summary since [IMDb's description](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3528756/) was a bit light:

> Two parallel stories about characters trapped in illogical endless spaces: two brothers and a detective locked on an infinite staircase, and a family locked on an infinite road - for a very long time.